# Why Async.StartChild does not take CancellationToken?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I am struggling to understand `Async.[StartChild|Start]` API design.
What I would like is to start an async process which does some tcp stream reading and calling a callback according to commands arriving on tcp.

As this async process does not really return any single value, it seems like I should use `Async.Start`. At some point I want to "close" my tcp client and `Async.Start takes CancellationToken, which gives me ability to implement 'close". So far so good.

The problem is, I would like to know when tcp client is done with cancellation. There is some buffer flushing work done, once Cancel is requested, so I do not want to terminate application before tcp client is done cleanup. But `Async.Start` returns unit, which means I have no way of knowing when such async process is complete. So, looks like `Async.StartChild` should help. I should be able to invoke cancellation, and when cleanup is done, this async will invoke next contiuation in chain (or throw an exception?). But... `Async.StartChild` does not take CancellationToken, only timeout.

Why `Async.StartChild` implements just single case of cancellation strategy (timeout) instead of exposing more generic way (accept CancellationToken)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first part of the question - if you need to do some cleanup work, you can just put it in `finally` and it will be called when the workflow is cancelled. For example:

```
let work = 
  async {
    try
      printfn "first work"
      do! Async.Sleep 1000
      printfn "second work"
    finally
      printfn "cleanup" }
```

Say you run this using `Async.Start`, wait for 500ms and then cancel the computation:

```
let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
Async.Start(work, cts.Token)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
cts.Cancel()
```

The output will be "first work, cleanup". As you can see, cancelling the computation will run all the `finally` clauses.

To answer the second part of the question - if you need to wait until the work completes, you can use `RunSynchronously` (but then, perhaps you do not actually need asynchronous workflows, if you are blocking anyway...).

The following starts a background process that cancels the main work after 500ms and then starts the main work synchronously:

```
let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()

async {
  do! Async.Sleep(500)
  cts.Cancel() } |> Async.Start

try Async.RunSynchronously(work, cancellationToken=cts.Token)
with :? System.OperationCanceledException -> ()
printfn "completed"
```

This prints "first work, cleanup, completed" - as you can see, the `RunSynchronously` call was blocked until the work was cancelled.

Comment: Ah-ha, now i remember that `CancellationToken.Register` is invoked *synchronously* from `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`. So all my cancellation callbacks, such as `Async.OnCancel`, etc will be called synchronously and i do not have to worry about killing background thread in-progress.